# Java: loop and multiply

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to loop through my arraylist such a way that,

if it's int i = 0 = b(0), it will **eliminate** b(0) and multiply

```
b.get(1)*b.get(2) = 3*6
```

if it's int i = 1 = b(1), it will **eliminate** b(1) and multiply

```
b.get(0)*b.get(2) = 1*6
```

if it's int i = 2 = b(2),it will **eliminate** b(2) and multiply

```
b.get(0)*b.get(1) = 1*3
```

I tried but it's not what i wanted

```
1*3
1*6
3*1
3*6
6*1
6*3
```

code

```
ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();
b.add(1);
b.add(3);
b.add(6);

for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < b.size(); j++) {
        if(b.get(i) != b.get(j)) {
            System.out.println(b.get(i) + "*" + b.get(j));
        }
    }
}
```

---

By doing this

```
for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
    for(int j = i+1; j < b.size(); j++) {
        if(b.get(i) != b.get(j)) {
            System.out.println(b.get(i) + "*" + b.get(j));
        }
    }
}
```

I will get output of

```
1*3
1*6
3*6
```

which is wrong.

Desired output

```
3*6
1*6
1*3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just start the second loop from i+1 (and the if is not more needed)

`for(int j = i+1; j < b.size(); j++)`

EDIT:

```
for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < b.size(); j++){
        for(int k = j+1; k < b.size(); k++) {
           if(j != i && k != i)
               System.out.println(b.get(j) + "*" + b.get(k));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I didn't explain my question well enough, what I wanted is, if e.g I start the loop, start from int = 0 = b(0) which is 1, it will eliminate b(0)=1 and just multiply b(1) and b(2) so 3*6, now int i = 1 = b(1) so it will eliminate b(1) and multiply b(0) and b(2) so 1*6 and lastly now int = 2 = b(2) so it will eliminate b(2) and multiply b(0) and b(1) which is 1*3

Comment: by doing for(int j = i+1; j < b.size(); j++), I will get out of (1*3 1*6 3*6) which is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Just set the j loop to start from

```
i + 1
```

This will print the pairs only once.

Comment: I think I didn't explain my question well enough, what I wanted is, if e.g I start the loop, start from int = 0 = b(0) which is 1, it will eliminate b(0)=1 and just multiply b(1) and b(2) so 3*6, now int i = 1 = b(1) so it will eliminate b(1) and multiply b(0) and b(2) so 1*6 and lastly now int = 2 = b(2) so it will eliminate b(2) and multiply b(0) and b(1) which is 1*3

Comment: by doing for(int j = i+1; j < b.size(); j++), I will get out of (1*3
1*6
3*6) which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not care for order, all you want is to list all possible unordered pairs with distinct elements from the list of integers (`1`, `3`, and `6`) you provide.

So let us start by looping through the list for the first element:

```
for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); ++i) {
    // something with b.get(i)
}
```

Next we need the second element. If, for `j`, we start at index `0` again, we would need to check whether `j` is equal to `i`. In addition, when we get to some index greater than `0` with `i`, we would also loop with `j` through all elements smaller than `i`. This gives you the duplicates `6 * 3` and `3 * 6` and similar.

So we do not want `j = i` and we also do not want `j < i`. So we start with `j = i +`, which gives us all the pairings we want, and nothing more.

```
for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); ++i) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < b.size(); ++j) {
        // something with b.get(i)
    }
}
```

If you draw a multiplication table

```
   |  1  |  3  |  6
 1 | 1*1 | 1*3 | 1*6
 3 | 3*1 | 3*3 | 3*6
 6 | 6*1 | 6*3 | 6*6
```

you see, that we are looking at values from a triangle. We start with 1*3, 1*6 (and more, if we had further integers), and continue in the next row one column furter right with 3*6.

Comment: I think I didn't explain my question well enough, what I wanted is, if e.g I start the loop, start from int = 0 = b(0) which is 1, it will eliminate b(0)=1 and just multiply b(1) and b(2) so 3*6, now int i = 1 = b(1) so it will eliminate b(1) and multiply b(0) and b(2) so 1*6 and lastly now int = 2 = b(2) so it will eliminate b(2) and multiply b(0) and b(1) which is 1*3